# How to handle plurals in localisation objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, plural

I'm going through this page to see how to handle plurals.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW10

I've added an english.stringsdict which contains the following.

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>%d file(s) remaining</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
            <string>%#@files@</string>
            <key>files</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
                <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
                <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
                <string>d</string>
                <key>one</key>
                <string>%d file remaining</string>
                <key>other</key>
                <string>%d files remaining</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I've set the localisation property in the file inspector to english
I have a Localizable.strings also set to english which contains the following.

```
/* Message shown for remaining files */
"%d file(s) remaining" = "%d file(s) remaining";
```

I've set application language in schema to english.

I'm setting label text like this

```
self.label.text = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%d file(s) remaining", @"Message shown for remaining files"), count];
```

What is being displayed is "5 file(s) remaining"

What I want to display is 5 files remaining or 1 file remaining if there is one file.

Comment: Delete the line from Localizable.strings, and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Thanks and upvoted because the whole feature was new to me, so thanks very much! I can use it!.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks for the up vote. I still haven't gotten this to work. If you get it to work I would love to see a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same key in the Localizable.strings as in the Localizable.stringsdict. The system first looks into Localizable.strings and if the key is not found, he looks into Localizable.stringsdict.

Solution: Just remove

```
/* Message shown for remaining files */
"%d file(s) remaining" = "%d file(s) remaining";
```

from Localizable.strings